# add stroke in h1 using webkit-text-stroke css

Tags: css

I tried using stroke to apply border in h1

```
font-family: 'Lobster Regular',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
font-size: 133px;
color: #ff5a00!important;
-webkit-text-stroke: 7px rgb(255 255 255);
```

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STUOC.png)

what I want

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwlHx.png)

Comment: if you want the final result then we need your code i.e. HTML and CSS.

Comment: why not use text-shadow?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping sorry, I updated the post.

Comment: @MVB76 yes I did but couldn't get the result I wanted, text-shadow: -7px -7px 0 #ffffff, 7px -7px 0 #ffffff, -7px 7px 0 #ffffff, 7px 7px 0 #ffffff;

Answer (score 0):

### The `text-stroke` property is a non standarized property.

---

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke)

---

The best alternative is to use the `text-shadow` property like this:

```
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff, 1px 1px 0 #fff;
```

**However** this will only look good with short directives. Using larger numbers will always result in a flawed look.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap');

body {
  background: #212121;
}

.stroke {
  font-family: "Lobster", Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
  font-size: 133px;
  color: #ff5a00 !important;
  text-shadow: -7px -7px 0 #fff, 7px -7px 0 #fff, -7px 7px 0 #fff, 7px 7px 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="stroke" stroke="Font">
  Font
</h1>
```

---